# drupal7 page template for profile2 module

Tags: templates, profile, drupal-7

I want to present User fields from the profile2 module in drupal 7 in a custom template file.

I can edit profile2--bewerbungsprofil.tpl.php (where bewerbungsprofil is the name of the profile2 type) - but i want to edit the page.tpl.php-type output, so I have control over head and footer of the resulting html file.

Is there a special naming convention, like page--profile2--bewerbungsprofile.tpl.php, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try: page--profile-bewerbungsprofil.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to explain how template overrides are named

[[http://drupal.org/node/1089656]]

I think what you'd want to do is copy any tpl.php files into your local theme (sites/all/themes/yourtheme).